# Rails with google plus

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I wanted to know: How to implement google plus login with oauth 2.0 in rails 3 & also extract posts of a particular user.

Thanks and Regards,

Techtotie.

Answer (score 2):

The [PhotoHunt Ruby Server](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/ruby) sample application demonstrates a Ruby on Rails integration in Google+. There is more information in the Google+ developer documentation on [the Ruby PhotoHunt sample](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/ruby) itself.

The [WigWam sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-wigwam-server) application demonstrates Ruby on Rails integration using Google+ Sign-In as well. This sample application is used to demonstrate integration of Facebook and Google+ side-by-side. Documentation is available under [Adding Google+ to your Facebook integration](https://developers.google.com/+/best-practices/facebook).

The [Google+ Ruby Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ruby) demonstrates performing API calls using Ruby and is written using Sinatra, this may also be helpful if you are just getting started with Ruby and want a simpler demo (particularly if you don't want to simultaneously try and learn Ruby and RoR).